# Web - how can I show one div on first load and toggle between divs?

Tags: javascript, html, translation, blogger

I have a 2 divs (one for different languages on a website - spanish and English). I have two code icons which when clicked toggle between the two languages. The problem was I couldn't figure out how to load just one div when a user first visits the site, so I put a hide div by default in the code, but, then when the user clicks to another page in the website, it automatically defaults back to that language (Spanish). Is there a way to show just one div (Spanish) by default, but whatever user picks, that selection stays there no matter how they click around the website until the user changes to English?

I am writing this as a html/javascript widget on blogger. my website is www.salsacuenca.com. 
Thanks!!! this is what I have so far:

```
<script language="javascript">
divHideShow('divA','divB')
function divHideShow(divToHide,divToShow) 
    {   var divH = document.getElementById(divToHide);
        var divS = document.getElementById(divToShow);

            divH.style.display = "none";
            divS.style.display = "block";
    }         
</script>
<a href="javascript:divHideShow('divB','divA');"><img border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-7IbtHQEviyM/UabyRBv20WI/AAAAAAAACnM/4SNwvWStxPA/s1600/1369913448_United+States+of+America(USA).png" /></a>  
  <a href="javascript:divHideShow('divA','divB');"><img border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8zP0OAklQ3c/UabyRLUT-6I/AAAAAAAACnQ/GGULC6u9csE/s1600/1369913395_Ecuador.png" /></a>
    <br />
```

Comment: if you are using a server you can send the type of language in the query to the next page and propagate, if you are using all pages in one (div pages) you can do it locally using a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use cookies to set the selected value and using that cookie you could select the div later.

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

You could check if the cookie is set or not. If set you could display a div according to the value of that or you could set the cookie  and display the other